# How to do Wilcoxon test on columns between two dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, hypothesis-test

I have two dataframes:

```
D9 <- as.data.frame(DF$As,DF$Cd,DF$Cu,DF$Cr,DF$Ni,DF$Pb,DF$Zn)
D10 <- as.data.frame(DO$As,DO$Cd,DO$Cu,DO$Cr,DO$Ni,DO$Pb,DO$Zn)
```

And want to apply wilcox test on each columns (DF$As,DO$As) and so on.
I tried the following code:

```
lapply(ncol(D9), function(i) {wilcox.test((D9[,i]),(D10[,i]))})
```

And the output was:

```
[[1]]
Wilcoxon rank sum test
data:  (D9[, i]) and (D10[, i])
W = 107, p-value = 0.9834
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

So my question is - what am I doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) where all the variables are defined so we can copy/paste into R to test possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

We have two different data-frames **d1** & **d2** of sizes **N** observations of **X** variables and **N** observations of **Y** variables respectively.
For finding Wilcoxon-Matt-Whitney test between every columns of these two different data frames **d1** & **d2**:
**1.** Reading data :

```
d1 <- data.frame(read.table("data1", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = ""))
d2 <- data.frame(read.table("data2", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = ""))
```

Assume number of columns in **d1** is greater than number of columns in **d2**

```
length(colnames(d1)) >= length(colnames(d2))
```

**2.** Declaring a Matrix to store p-values

```
pvalue <- matrix(nrow = length(colnames(d2)), ncol = (length(colnames(d1)))
```

**3.** Now for Wilcoxon-Matt-Whitney test for each column of **d2$1** with **d1$1, d1$2, d1$3, ...** and so on

```
for(i in 1:length(colnames(d2))){
  for(j in 1:length(colnames(d1))){
    pvalue[i,j]<-wilcox.test(d2[,i], d1[,j], paired=TRUE)$p.value 
    colnames(pvalue) <- colnames(d1)
    rownames(pvalue) <- colnames(d2)} }
```

**Note :** This method will also works fine if we want to perform Wilcoxon-Matt-Whitney test on single data-frame to find relation between one column with another columns of same data-frame.

```
d3 <- data.frame(read.table("data3", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = ""))  
pvalue <- matrix(nrow = length(colnames(d3)), ncol = (length(colnames(d3)))
```

Now for Wilcoxon-Matt-Whitney test for each column of **d3$1** with **d3$1, d3$2, d3$3, ...** and so on

```
for(i in 1:length(colnames(d3))){
  for(j in 1:length(colnames(d3))){
    pvalue[i,j]<-wilcox.test(d3[,i], d3[,j], paired=TRUE)$p.value 
    colnames(pvalue) <- colnames(d3)
    rownames(pvalue) <- colnames(d3)} }
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that `ncol(D9)` will only return a single number, so `lapply` will only iterate over that single number. Use `1:ncol(D9)` to start at the first column (or use `seq.int(ncol(D9))`. See the difference between `lapply(9, print)` and `lapply(1:9, print)`

Alternative you can just map over the columns directly with

```
Map(wilcox.test, D9, D10)
```

since data.frames are really just lists.

Answer (score 0):

lapply needs a vector, so @MrFlick's suggesting will probably be of help (you actually only ran one wilcox test)

You could also get iterative printouts through a loop

```
for(i in 1:ncol(D9)){
    summary(wilcox.text(D9[,i],D10[,i]))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is alternative using a package, doing wilcox test between iris first columns 1-2 and columns 3-4.

```
library(matrixTests)
col_wilcoxon_twosample(iris[,1:2], iris[,3:4])

             obs.x obs.y obs.tot statistic       pvalue alternative location.null exact corrected
Sepal.Length   150   150     300     19249 1.702530e-26   two.sided             0 FALSE      TRUE
Sepal.Width    150   150     300     22362 1.295486e-49   two.sided             0 FALSE      TRUE
```